# I want to remove the localhost/host-name from message popup. How I do this?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

[image]

kendo.confirm("Do you want to confirm..").then(function () {}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://www.telerik.com/forums/dialog-change-kendo-confirm-title#Dko30-JxG0C7aSP1unMNbA) you can see a topic related.

just in case the link disappears:

```
    .k-confirm .k-window-titlebar::before {
    content: 'Confirmation';
    }

    .k-confirm .k-window-titlebar .k-dialog-title {
        visibility:collapse;
    }
```